# io-ts - Validate array contains one of each object with specific properties and values

Tags: typescript

I looked at the https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/ docs but cant find the validation I need.

I have an array of object literals each with specific properties and values.

I want to validate that comboItems is not empty and contains a min and max of 3 objects AND that there is an itemType === 'Entree' AND an itemType==='Side' AND an itemType==='Beverage'

```
import * as t from "io-ts";
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function'
import { fold, isRight, isLeft } from 'fp-ts/Either'

enum ItemTypeEnum {'MEALS_GROUP'='MEALS_GROUP', 'ENTREES'='ENTREES', 'SIDES_GROUP'='SIDES_GROUP', 'BEVERAGES_GROUP'='BEVERAGES_GROUP'}

const Entree = t.type({
    itemType: t.literal(ItemTypeEnum.ENTREES),
})
const Side = t.type({
    itemType: t.literal(ItemTypeEnum.SIDES_GROUP),
})

type Entree = t.TypeOf<typeof Entree>
type Side = t.TypeOf<typeof Side>

export const Meal = t.type({
    comboItems: t.readonlyArray(t.union([Entree, Side]))
})
```

This shows as a success (which is expected):

```
console.log(pipe(
    Meal.decode({comboItems: [{itemType: ItemTypeEnum.ENTREES}, {itemType: ItemTypeEnum.SIDES_GROUP}]}),
    fold(
        // failure handler
        (errors) => `error: ${JSON.stringify(errors)}`,
        // success handler
        (a) => `success: ${JSON.stringify(a)}`
    )
    )
)
```

But this also shows as a success, which should not because it's missing  {{itemType: ItemTypeEnum.SIDES_GROUP}

```
console.log(pipe(
    Meal.decode({comboItems: [{itemType: ItemTypeEnum.ENTREES}]}),
    fold(
        // failure handler
        (errors) => `error: ${JSON.stringify(errors)}`,
        // success handler
        (a) => `success: ${JSON.stringify(a)}`
    )
    )
)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?